# Egger's test, Trim and fill method and funnel plots for three-level meta-analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis, metafor, publication-bias, funnel-plot

I have performed a three-level meta-analysis in R (based on correlations) to estimate an overall association and to perform moderator analyses following guidelines of Assink & Wibbelink (2016). Now I am trying to test for publication bias with the Egger's test, Trim and fill method and/or inspection of funnel plots. My question is: does the same method for these tests for publication bias apply to a three-level method? I used this [book](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/) and I understand the methods, but these were not applied to three-level meta-analyses specifically. Do we use the same codes, or does anyone know where to find an example for a three-level meta-analysis?

Code overall association:

```
*ass <- rma.mv(zi, vi, random = list(~1 | effect size, ~ 1 | study number), tdist = TRUE, data = dataset)*
```

For example, I used this code from the book to create an object to test for publication bias (m.cor). Or does this not apply to the three-level meta-analysis? Because after Trim and fill, how do I estimate the overall association again?

```
*m.cor <- metacor(cor = r,
                 N = samplesize,
                 studlab = author,
                 data = dataset,
                 fixed = FALSE,
                 random = TRUE,
                 method.tau = "REML",
                 hakn = TRUE,
                 title = "meta-analysis")*

Egger's test:
*metabias(m.cor, method.bias = "linreg")*

Trim and fill method:
*res9 <- rma(zi, vi, data = dataset, method = "FE")
rtf <- trimfill(res9)
rtf
funnel(rtf)*

trim and fill:
*m.cor$I2
tf <- trimfill(m.cor)
summary(tf)*
```

Comment: Does https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2020-December/002491.html help? You might like to look at the whole thread.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful for the funnel plot. I wonder if there is also more information about the Egger's test (on the forum it doesn't align) and Trim and fill method.

Comment: Egger's method uses the same variables as the funnel plot. Trim and fill has received criticism and seems to have fallen out of fashion.

Comment: That's crucial information, thank you. Would this be correct: egger_multi <- rma.mv(zi, vi, random = ~ 1 | studynr, mods = ~ vi, data = dataset).